# Opening Drawer from different file (Material-UI, React)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to open a drawer in file "dashboard" from the file "Navbar", As you may have guessed i want to open the drawer which needs to be in the dashboard file from the navbar, sounds easy enough but i just can get it to work. I have tried multiple methods, One of the sorta worked:

---

Having the toggle function and drawerOpen state in a Layout file so the structure workes as follow:
Click event in navbar.js runs the toggle function in Layout --> Toggle function in layout changes the drawerOpen state --> The drawerOpen state gets passed into Dashboard.js via props which is then controlling the drawer open state. The only downside to using this method is that all the animations don't work (slowly showing the drawer in and out etc)

---

So i thought i need to have the drawerOpen state and the function directly inside the Dashboard file, But how do i get the button in navbar.js to run a function in dashboard.js?

I hope i explained it well enough for you to understand, any idea's would be appreciated! If i need to explain some more stuff please let me know!

Edit 1  the without the animations working
Layout.js  (there are ofcourse more routes etc but i removed them to make the file cleaner):

```js
const Layout = () => {
  const [dashBoardSideNavOpen, setDashBoardSideNavOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const dashBoardSideNavToggle = () => {
    setDashBoardSideNavOpen(!dashBoardSideNavOpen);
  };

  const dashBoardSideNavClose = () => {
    setDashBoardSideNavOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar
        dashBoardSideNavToggle={dashBoardSideNavToggle}
      />
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/dashboard"
          component={props => (
            <DashBoard
              {...props}
              dashBoardSideNavOpen={dashBoardSideNavOpen}
              dashBoardSideNavToggle={dashBoardSideNavToggle}
              dashBoardSideNavClose={dashBoardSideNavClose}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>

  );
};

export default Layout
```

Navbar.js:

```
const NavBar = ({dashBoardSideNavToggle}) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
          <Toolbar>     
            <Box style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
              <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={dashBoardSideNavToggle}>
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Box>
            <Typography variant="h4" style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
              <Link component={RouterLink} to="/" color="inherit" underline="none">
                Title
              </Link>
            </Typography>
            <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={userSideNavToggle}>
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.offset} />
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

DashBoard.js:

```
const DashBoard = ({dashBoardSideNavOpen, dashBoardSideNavToggle, dashBoardSideNavClose}) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Drawer
          variant="temporary"
          anchor={'left'}
          open={dashBoardSideNavOpen}
          onOpen={dashBoardSideNavToggle}
          onClose={dashBoardSideNavToggle}
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper
          }}
          ModalProps={{
            keepMounted: true
          }}
        >
          {drawerContent}
        </Drawer>
        <Fragment>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path={'/dashboard/overview'}
              component={Overview}
            />
          </Switch>
        </Fragment>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: please add some code. drawer trigger, or components or something.

Comment: I added a lot of code, i made the smallest understandle version i could make hopefully it makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to need to hold the `open` state in a common parent component to the dashboard and the navbar, and then have the state and a function to update the state passed down into whatever component needs to control it. Here is a simple minimal example of the type of solution you are looking for:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <Controller open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen} />
      <Drawer open={open} />
    </div>
  )
}

const Controler = ({ open, onOpenChange }) => {
  return <button onClick={() => onOpenChange(!open)}>toggle drawer</button>
}

const Drawer = ({ open }) => {
  if (open) return <div>I am open!!</div>
  return <div>I am closed!!</div>
}
```

EDIT:
A `<Route>` should not be passed an inlined component (unless the component that holds the routes **never** updates. You should really only pass in components that do not need to take any props. When setting the `component` to an inlined functional component, that will lead to the instance of the rendered component being destroyed and re-mounted whenever the route contained re-renders (the functional component function gets redefined). **I think this is why your animation is most likely not working correctly.**

The simplest solution might be to create a context which can send the necessary drawer functions down the tree, that way you don't need to pass them through as props. Something like:

```
const DrawerContext = React.createContext({ setOpen: () => {}, open: false });

const Parent = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <DrawerContext.Provider value={{setOpen}}>
      <div>
        <Controller/>
        <Drawer />
      </div>
    </DrawerContext.Provider
  )
}

const Controler = () => {
  const { open, setOpen } = useContext(DrawerContext);
  return <button onClick={() => onOpenChange(!open)}>toggle drawer</button>
}

const Drawer = () => {
  const { open } = useContext(DrawerContext);

  if (open) return <div>I am open!!</div>
  return <div>I am closed!!</div>
}
```

Comment: I think this is what i was doing already, i edited the question with a lot of code, it seems like we are doing the same but this causes the drawer to have no animation whatsoever. Thats why i think i must move the "controler" part into the dashboard.js

Comment: Okay so I think there might be a very subtle bug going on in your code. You want to avoid passing in an inlined component into a Route, because every time the `App` re-renders, the component literally gets re-defined leading to the instance being destroyed and then remounted. You are probably going to need to do a rather large change to fix this. I will update my reply with some possible solutions...

Comment: Yea i know its not the best way to do it but i wouldn't know how i can pass props in a route any other way (any help in making that cleaner would be appreciated also) but would this actually have anything to do with the animations not showing up?

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the problem, i was already using redux so i just moved all the function over to redux and now its working perfect!